# I need to pass an array of structures to a function [large code]

Tags: c, arrays, function, vector, structure

I've been working on this for days but can't seem to make it work out.

Sorry in advance for the unholy length of this, so if anyone takes the time to go through it and try to understand this mess, I'd owe you.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct cart {
    int id;
    char *nume;
} cart;

typedef struct pach {
    int id, idCartier, strada, numar, prioritate, codificare;
    float greutate;
    char* mesaj;
    int adresa[18];
} pach;

typedef struct post {
    int id, nrPachete;
    int vector[50];
} post;

int citeste(int *nrP, cart *cartier, pach *pachet, int *nrC) {
    printf("Punctul 1\n");
    int i, j;     
    scanf("%d", nrC);
    for (i = 0; i < *nrC; i++) {
        cartier[i].id = i;
        char aux[500]; 
        scanf("%s", aux);
        cartier[i].nume = malloc(strlen(aux) + 1);  
        cartier[i].nume = aux;
        printf("%d %s\n", cartier[i].id, cartier[i].nume);
    }
    scanf("%d", nrP);
    for (i = 0; i < *nrP; i++) {
        pachet[i].id = i;
        char aux[500];
        for (j = 0; j < 18; j++)
            scanf("%d", &pachet[i].adresa[j]);
        scanf("%d %f", &pachet[i].prioritate, &pachet[i].greutate);
        getchar();
        fgets(aux, 256, stdin);
        pachet[i].mesaj = malloc(strlen(aux) + 1);
        pachet[i].mesaj = aux;
        printf("%d\n", pachet[i].id);
        for (j = 0; j < 18; j++)
            printf("%d ", pachet[i].adresa[j]);
        printf("\n%d %.6f ", pachet[i].prioritate, pachet[i].greutate); 
        printf("%s", pachet[i].mesaj);
    }
    return *nrP;
}

void extrage(int *nrP, pach *pachet) {
    printf("\nPunctul 2\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < *nrP; i++) {
        pachet[i].idCartier = 0;
        pachet[i].strada = 0;
        pachet[i].numar = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            pachet[i].idCartier += pachet[i].adresa[j] * pow(2, (4 - j));
        for (j = 5; j < 10; j++)
            pachet[i].strada += pachet[i].adresa[j] * pow(2, (9 - j));
        for (j = 10; j < 18; j++)
            pachet[i].numar += pachet[i].adresa[j] * pow(2, (17 - j));
        printf("%d %d ", pachet[i].id, pachet[i].idCartier);
        printf("%d %d\n", pachet[i].strada, pachet[i].numar);
    }
}

void distribuie(int *nrP, pach *pachet, post *postas, int *nrC, cart *cartier) {    
    printf("Punctul 3\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < *nrC; i++) {        // FOR-1A
        postas[i].nrPachete = 0;
        postas[i].id = i;
        for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            postas[i].vector[j] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < *nrC; i++) {        // FOR-1B
        for (j = 0; j < *nrP; j++) {        
            if (cartier[i].id == pachet[j].idCartier) {
                postas[i].vector[postas[i].nrPachete] = pachet[j].id;
                postas[i].nrPachete++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d %d ", postas[i].id, postas[i].nrPachete);
        for (j = 0; j < postas[i].nrPachete; j++)
            printf("%d ", postas[i].vector[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }


}


void ordoneaza(pach *pachet, int *nrC, post *postas) {
    printf("Punctul 4\n");
    pach aux;
    int i, j, k = 0, schimbat = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < *nrC; i++) {
        while (schimbat) {
            schimbat = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < postas[i].nrPachete - k; j++)
                if (pachet[postas[i].vector[j]].prioritate < pachet[postas[i].vector[j+1]].prioritate) {
                    aux = pachet[postas[i].vector[j]];
                    pachet[postas[i].vector[j]] = pachet[postas[i].vector[j+1]];
                    pachet[postas[i].vector[j+1]] = aux;
                    schimbat = 1;
                }
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;
        schimbat = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < postas[i].nrPachete; j++) {
            for (k = j; k < postas[i].nrPachete; k++) {
                if (pachet[postas[i].vector[j]].prioritate == pachet[postas[i].vector[k]].prioritate) 
                    if (pachet[postas[i].vector[j]].greutate < pachet[postas[i].vector[k]].greutate) {
                        aux = pachet[postas[i].vector[j]];
                        pachet[postas[i].vector[j]] = pachet[postas[i].vector[k]];
                        pachet[postas[i].vector[k]] = aux;
                    }
            }   
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < *nrC; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < postas[i].nrPachete; j++) {
            postas[i].vector[j] = pachet[postas[i].vector[j]].id;
            }
    for (i = 0; i < *nrC; i++) {
        printf("%d %d ", postas[i].id, postas[i].nrPachete);
        for (j = 0; j < postas[i].nrPachete; j++)
            printf("%d ", postas[i].vector[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main() {
    int nrP, nrC;
    pach pachet[1600];
    post postas[32];
    cart cartier[32];
    citeste(&nrP, &cartier[32], &pachet[1600], &nrC);
    extrage(&nrP, &pachet[1600]);
    distribuie(&nrP, &pachet[1600], &postas[32], &nrC, &cartier[32]);
    ordoneaza(&pachet[1600], &nrC, &postas[32]);
    return (0);
}
```

Short info on what the program does:

The citeste function should read the cartier and pachet structures. All of them. And then print those in a bit different format.

The extrage function should take every pachet, and use the adresa (written in BINARY) to convert its 3 parts and obtain the strada, numar and idCartier. Then also print those.

Distribuie checks if the pachet is distributed to a postas (distributed means pachet.idCartier == postas.id), if not it distributes it.

Ordoneaza takes every postas's vector and sorts it after the prioritate (or greutate if the prioritate-s are equal).

But it doesn't work as intended and also gives weird Segmentation Faults.

For example if I comment out the distribuie function, it gives me segfault right after extrage. If I put it back, it gives segfault right after doing it. And if I uncomment everything, it gives segfault at the end again.

If anyone actually read all of this and would be willing to reply, I'd highly appreciate it. Any bit of advice helps!

Comment: First of all you don't pass arrays like that. first function call should be citeste(&nrP, cartier, pachet, &nrc).

Comment: What you are doing is passing the address of an element that does not even exist since array indices should run from 0 to size-1.

Comment: `citeste(&nrP, &cartier[32], &pachet[1600], &nrC);`  --> `citeste(&nrP, cartier, pachet, &nrC);`, E.g. `&cartier[32]` meant The address of following elements of the last element.

Comment: You can't copy strings like that `cartier[i].nume = aux`, use `strcpy/strncpy/strdup` instead.

Comment: No point for removing all. Others should benefit from this as well.

Comment: Alright, sorry for that! Another question btw, how do I write a function that takes a string (sentence) , reverses the words in it & removes the (, : and space) characters? @glglgl

Comment: To ask another question, use the button "Ask question". It seems totally unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not read your code, but your title said you had trouble passing array of structures. I am attaching a working snippet hope it will help you get around your problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct employee{
int empId;
char name[10];
}EMP;

void arrayOfStruct(EMP *a, int size)
{
    printf("%d\t%d",a[0].empId,a[3].empId);    
}
int main()
{
   EMP NC[4];
   NC[0].empId = 9;
   NC[3].empId = 2;
   arrayOfStruct(&NC[0],sizeof(NC)/sizeof(NC[0]));
}
```

with the help of `size` you can never go beyond the memory allocated for structures.

In case you, want to pass higher dimensional arrays, you have to hard code all the size of arrays except the outer most.

```
void arrayOfStruct(EMP a[][4], int size)
{
    // to do
}

int main()
{
    EMP NC[2][4];
    ...
    arrayOfStruct(NC,sizeof(NC)/sizeof(NC[0]));
}
```

as you see, I did not specify the higher most size of array, which I am passing via other arguement.

**Why do I need to specify size of inner dimensions ?**

Lets take an example, for suppose you have `int[4][4]`, and you are trying to pass array to a function via `int[3][]`, how does a compiler know how many inner blocks to create, in other case via `int[][3]`, the compiler can easily understand that it has to make inner block of size 3 for each outer array.